# MessageBox отдельно от основной программы

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
MessageBox(NULL, L"Can't connect on Server", L"Error", MB_SYSTEMMODAL);
```

Во-первых, скажу, что MessageBox'a я вывел в отдельный поток (чтобы не ждать ответа пользователя), но дело в том, что мне нужно сделать так, чтобы после того, как закрылся процесс

```
ExitProcess(0);
```

MessageBox остался открытым (т.к. в нем указывается уведомление пользователю)

Пожалуйста, не предлагать

1. приостановку основного потока (т.к. я использую DLL, а не основную программу)
2. Запуск совершенно другой программы (я использую DLL, а не пишу программу)

   ---

Использую IDE Visual Studio 15 с набором средств v140.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ваши условия выполнить невозможно.

`MessageBox` бежит не сам по себе, а в рамках какого-либо процесса. По завершению процесса все его потоки умирают, и система принудительно уничтожает все окна, принадлежащие процессу. Поэтому требование о том, чтобы другой процесс не запускался, немедленно означает, что диалоговое окно исчезнет с завершением процесса.

---

Рассматривая проблему прагматически, я бы отказался от требования одного процесса, и запустил бы однострочный скрипт на VBS:

```
MsgBox "Can't connect to server", 4096, "Error"
```

(запускать как `cscript путь-к-файлу.vbs`) Да, вам придётся таскать мелкий файл с собой, или создать его на лету во временном каталоге.

(Параметры для `MsgBox` описаны, например, [здесь](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/vbscript/vbscript_dialog_boxes.htm).)

Comment: а если через bat и какой-нибудь rundll?

Comment: @Grundy: Можно, это по сути то же самое. Просто VBScript писать легче, чем подыскивать параметры для rundll.

Comment: @VladD спасибо, помогли

Comment: @Кастиэль: Пожалуйста!